# What type of neural net to use to distinguish between real and fake images?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I want to implement a netwrok that know to distinguish between real and fake given images.
I don't want to use GAN bc it will be an overkill (training generator and discriminator and I already have the images).

What is the prefered framework to do this?
Does binary classifier is what I need?

Comment: There are too many parameters to this problem to give a good answer. I would recommend looking into transfere learning: https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Yes, binary classification sounds like a reasonable way to frame your problem.

GANs would be more suitable if you wanted to *generate* new images. In that case you could train a generator and a discriminator, and then use the former and discard the latter.

As I understand it, discriminator networks typically don't get used on their own (which appears to have been your line of thinking). The reason is that they become tightly coupled to the generator they've been trained with, and don't necessarily generalise beyond that.